# When are you using too much AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Over the last year, we did developed a system that uses many AJAX call. From the look of things now, I'm wondering when is too much of a good thing (AJAX) is simply too much. So here my question. When do you know you have been using too much AJAX? What is your rule of thumbs when you are creating web application.

Edit: Is there such a this a AJAX overusage?

I read the question [is there somthing like too much AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921963/is-there-something-like-too-much-ajax-how-do-you-handle-screen-resizing-due-to/). But it only provide the connection to the server issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it only depends on what you want search engines can find on your site.
If you want they can find every word in every corner, don´t use ajax.

If it is a private area, where a user must be logged in, there is no limit. A search engine can´t find such contents.

For web applications, I´ve begun to make the whole page in javascript & ajax. So you never have to reload the page. This makes things much easier for you.